# How to show XSL-converted XML as a part of an HTML page?

Tags: html, xml, iframe, xslt

Can I embed an XML file in HTML without using iFrames?
I want to show XSL-transformed XML(which, is HTML as a result of transformation) as a part of my HTML document. Hope this makes it clearer.

If my description of problem is unclear, please tell me and I will try to explain it more.

Comment: Yes, the description is unclear... specifically, you should elaborate on the purpose of the embedding. Does it need to store data or do you intend to display that XML on the page (as-is or transformed into HTML). That is three questions! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use browser based XSL transformation routines to convert an XML string into an XMLDocument or HTML output that can then be applied into any page element.

The steps could be briefly summarized as:

1. Load an XML string from a resource (or as the result of an AJAX hit).
2. Load the XML document into an Xml document object (code differs for Browsers - IE uses the ActiveXObject MSXML - DOMDocument, while Mozilla uses the built-in `implementation` to create a Document. Chrome on the other hand uses the built-in `XmlHttpRequest` object as the only available XML document object.)
3. Load the XSL document similarly and set its arguments.
4. Transform the XML and obtain output as a string.
5. Apply the string output to any page element.

Note that the code differs for each browser so it may be simpler to use a public JS framework such as JQuery or Prototype.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use html entities. For example this is how you would write a name tag
&lt;name&gt;.

More reading [here](http://www.cookwood.com/html/extras/entities.html#html)

Comment: Hm... Somehow this answers the question, yet somehow it does not.

Comment: I don't see an answer from Tomalak... maybe he deleted it.

Comment: @cerebrus - exactly, he didnt attempt to answer!